# I am trying to fetch value from Firebase Remoteconfig but values are not fetching and only getting defaults value in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

Below is my code,Even I am getting false value for **task.result**
.Anybody please can help me?

```
   val mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
    val configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600)
        .setFetchTimeoutInSeconds(60)
        .build()
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)

    //---defult value
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you provide more details?

If you are an Android developer and using Android Studio, you can integrate with Firebase RC easily with a few clicks.

To investigate the problem, you should check:

1. whether your RC is setting correctly
2. If you keeps getting the default values, it might be the app's signals don't match the condition you set in the RC template.

Comment: Yes,I solved issue.The problem was with RC template.I had added value of RC in different app and was fetching in another project.